# Access information in hidden columns with JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, view-formatting

I am trying to format a document library in our SharePoint Online platform.

The goal is to have a row with a video thumbnail, title and short description. The title is not the same as the video file and the thumbnail is also a separate png image. Therefore I have created additional columns that contain this information, but I don't want these columns to be shown.

**Problem:** When I hide the columns with the title or thumbnail, I cannot access the information using JSON formatting. The field where the title and thumbnail were before are empty when I hide the two columns.

How can I access the information within the hidden columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **known behavior** in SharePoint.

In order to format a column or view using JSON, the column you are referencing in JSON code **must be included in the list view**.

According to [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting),

> You construct a JSON object that describes the elements that are displayed when a field is included in a list view, and the styles to be applied to those elements.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I think there is no workaround for this as of now. You have to include the columns in the list view

Comment: There seems to be some sort of workaround here, but I have read the article and the tips in the comments multiple times and cannot understand what they are suggesting:  https://devscopeninjas.azurewebsites.net/2019/03/18/column-formatting-with-a-column-not-present-in-the-view/

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario I can use a calculated column and in JSON formatting use @currentField to work with the looked up value, e.g. creating a URL out of it which is read only since it is calculated.

If you need to work with two looked up values, maybe JSON can split these into variables?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. Calculated column was the answer.
In my list there are 3 choice columns. I created a calculated column combining these 3 columns and with a column formatting I replaced text with corresponding dots.
Now I can hide the 3 wide columns and replace them with a simple graphical representation.
Custom hover text has been added to help users identify what the dots represent.

Calculated column:

```
=[Market Risk]&" "&[Tech Risk]&" "&[Market Attractiveness]
```

Column formatting :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(replaceAll(@currentField,'Low Attractiveness',''),'Medium Attractiveness',''),'High Attractiveness',''),'High',''),'Low',''),'Medium','')",
  "style": {
    "font-size": "18px"
  },
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "Market Risk / Tech Risk / Market Attractiveness",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "padding": "10px"
      }
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]